# WP appending -2 to the end of my slug. Where are the originals stored so I can delete them?

Tags: slug

I've been learning about taxonomies, custom posts etc though a lot of trial and error. I finally have it working how I want, however now I am getting some conflict with my desired slugs. I can't name my category "venue" because someplace in the database, that's already taken (I assume) - even though I've deleted the category that used it. Now when I try adding the category that I want to use the "venue" slug, WP automatically makes it "venue-2", which I definitely don't want in my url as the folder. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Any progress on this question?

Comment: @kaiser, I'd love to know how to change that as well. I'd rather avoid messing with the database itself.

Comment: Clear your trash posts, pages etc. deleting items permanently.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam That should actually be an answer - or search up an answer that you can take and mark this one as duplicate. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

This can also be caused by uploading images with the same file name as the post/page. In my case, I uploaded an image called 'careers.jpg' before I created a page called 'Careers', so the page was getting the '-2' appended. To fix it, I just changed the slug on the image, then I was able to change the slug on the page.

Comment: The media permalink field can be hidden by default, btw. Here's more info on how to find it: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232569/change-media-item-permalink

Answer (score 5):

The slug is stored in the `post_name` column of your `posts` table. I'd recommend searching that table first before manually assigning that slug, though.

Comment: thank you! this is exactly the information I needed. It's not letting me manually assign the slug, which is a failsafe I guess.

Comment: What are you using? You can do this with PHPMyAdmin; I have in the past.

Comment: @Joseph, how about custom post type taxonomy slugs? I don't even have any CPT posts left yet taxonomy keeps adding numbers to slugs...

Comment: Do a complete search of your database for the slug that you are trying to use.

Comment: Thank you. still valuable advice in 2019

Answer (score 2):

There is another cause for Wordpress appending `-2` at the end: When the slug only contains numbers. This is not allowed.

Example: I wanted to name my page `2016` and even though there has never been a 2016 in the database the slug always turned into `2016-2`.
As far as I remember this is because numbers have a special meaning for workpress (path variables) and they couldn't be distinguished.

So my solution was to manually rename the slug to `year-2016` which looks nicer than this "-2" suffix.

Comment: great found, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Usually when Wordpress appends the "-2" to a slug, that means you still have the old content, that you meant to delete, in the trash. Be sure to empty your wordpress trash, then try making the slug.

To access the pages in the trash, open the Pages / All pages menu, then click on the "Bin" section that appears on the right hand side of the "All" section. Note that if there is no items in the bin, this section will not appear.

Comment: Is there a trash for slugs somewhere then? :)