# Change media item permalink

Tags: permalinks

I have an image whose permalink is domain.com/books
I would now like a page located at this permalink.

Is there a way to change the image's permalink?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes!

1. Go to your Media Library
2. Click the Image
3. Click the "Edit more details" link
4. If you cannot see a way to edit the permalink, click the "Screen Options" button at the top of the page and select the "Slug" checkbox.
5. Edit the Slug/Permalink value
6. Click Update

### Edit

If for some reason you cannot Edit the Images' Permalink... you could:

1. Delete Image
2. Change your Pages' Permalink
3. Re-Upload Image

Comment: Thank you, but when i go into edit mode for that item, the permalink is not editable (as it is usually for posts/pages)

Comment: Hmm are you using Wordpress.org or Wordpress.com?

Comment: Wordpress installation on my own domain/hosting (i guess that mean org)

Comment: That is odd. Have you tried disabling your Plugins and changing themes?

Comment: Anyway I added another method to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the 2nd option: i assume that the actual path to the filename would be the same (i would not have to change where it appears anywhere on the site)?

Comment: Regarding the 2nd option, you would have to go through your content and update where appropriate with the new image.

Comment: As a last resort option, you can adjust the _post_title_ via the database for the image. I don't normally recommend this option, but in this case, it might be your only option. Using a tool like phpMyAdmin can help with this. I recommend taking note of the images ID (check the URL when editing the image - _wp-admin/post.php?post=114&action=edit_ - ID is **114** in this example). Search your wp_posts table for that ID, change the post_title value to the desired slug.

Comment: I can't figure out how to unvote this but [Cole's suggestion for post_title is incorrect](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232569/change-media-item-permalink#comment404450_232581); the value to edit is in the **post_name** column.

Comment: The correct answer is by Devin Peterson.

Comment: Who marked this answer as correct? It is WRONG! There is no edit link next to the permalink. (There is for pages and posts. But not for media) and the second suggestion is so out of place that it shows that the author didn't bother reading the question.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The one below by Andy is the right one. All you have to do update the slug, which you can show from the Screen Options.

Comment: Such a garbage answer. Did you even try what you wrote prior to your EDIT?
Such things are what make this SO so bad, it is full of wrong advice that is written to get points and not to communicate actual truth.

Comment: No need to touch the database. If you do not see how to edit the permalink, to click on the Screen Options link at the top of the page and select "Slug". The option to edit the permalink/slug will now appear. I will try to edit the answer to include this.

Comment: If Wordpress does not allow you to change the permalink to the one you want - usually because Wordpress stores old permalinks one of which might be the same as the one you want to use - try this solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/261630/how-to-delete-unused-url

Answer (score 64):

1. Go to Media Library
2. Find the Image
3. Click Edit Image

[image]

4. Click Edit more details (at bottom right, very easy to miss)

[image]

5. Find the Screen Options (top right) and enable the Slug checkbox

[image]

6. Scroll down to the slug box and change the slug to whatever you want.
7. Click Update!

Comment: This worked for me since I couldn't edit the permalink but had no problem editing the slug.

Comment: this is the correct answer, it works, the answer selected by OP does not. Please upvote.

Comment: This is the correct method.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: Still works in 2021, thanks!

Comment: "Titelform" is the German word for "slug" here.

Answer (score 10):

In Media Library, I noticed that when media file is not Attached to a page the permalink is not editable. When they are attached, permalink editing is permitted.

Comment: I was still able to edit the link when the media file is not attached to a page or post, just need to do a couple extra steps - see [Devin's Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/283456/48698)

Comment: This works for me while other solutions do not

Answer (score 9):

On the edit page, 
1. click the screen options downward triangle in the upper right of the screen
2. Check "Slug" under Boxes.
3. Update
4. Scroll down to Slug box.
5. Type in what you want to call the link.

This doesn't change the link location. Just the link name, which is what I was trying to figure out since I didn't want it as the name of the file I uploaded.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! this also changes the post_name in the