# How to delete unused URL?

Tags: urls

If I modify the URL of a post, that URL is still being used by the post. If I try to create a new post and use the hidden URL, I'll get an error.

Is there some way to find all of these hidden, unused URLs and delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you change the slug of a permalink **on posts** ( and custom post types with post capabilities ), WordPress will save the old slug in the post_meta table with the key `_wp_old_slug`. On a normal installation the old slug should redirect to the new slug using [`wp_old_slug_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_old_slug_redirect/). There are a couple ways to remove them, the easiest is probably [SQL directly](http://snippet.fm/snippets/delete-posts-old-slugs-from-database-in-wordpress/):

```
/**
 * Delete posts old slugs from database in WordPress
 */
function delete_old_slugs() {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->get_results( "DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_old_slug'" );
}
delete_old_slugs();
```

You may also be able to find a plugin to do the work for you, the first one that I could find is [Remove Old Slugs plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-old-slugspermalinks/) which will also supply you a list of the old slugs which seems neat.

Comment: Unfortunately, that plugin doesn't seem to work. I had a page called sample-page. I renamed it to sample-page-2 and updated. The plugin doesn't show the old URL.

Comment: @4thSpace The slug redirection feature hasn't been implemented for pages, only posts ( or post types with post capabilities ). I've tested the plugin and it works as expected, for posts.

Comment: ah - I see. Thanks. Do you know of anything that works for Pages?